# ffmpeg: fade-in not rendered when used in conjunction with fade-out

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a video file I want to fade in and out over a duration of three seconds each.

My code is, run over WSL on WIN 10 pro 22H2:

`ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf "fade=t=in:st=0:d=3,fade=t=out:st=169.288000:d=3" videofaded.mp4`

Expected behaviour: Fade from and to black over 3s. This is what I got in the past.
What I get: No fade in at all but a fade out as specified.

If I run `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf "fade=t=in:st=0:d=3" -c:a copy fadein.mp4` to just fade in everything works as expected.

Can anybody help my identify the problem? I want to fade in and out in the same turn as there are a couple of videos to edit.

Thanks,
Chris

Here is my ffmpeg output:

```
ffmpeg version 4.2.7-0ubuntu0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-nvenc --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fffda8a7300] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none, 1920x1080, 1087 kb/s): unspecified pixel format
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '20231106_Einfuehrung_Word_Mark_Fragen.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:02:52.29, start: 0.016000, bitrate: 1126 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none, 1920x1080, 1087 kb/s, 16 fps, 16 tbr, 10k tbn, 20k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 16000 Hz, mono, fltp, 72 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
File 'videofaded.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x7fffda8c2c40] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2 AVX512
[libx264 @ 0x7fffda8c2c40] profile High, level 4.0
[libx264 @ 0x7fffda8c2c40] 264 - core 155 r2917 0a84d98 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2018 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=24 lookahead_threads=4 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=16 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'videofaded.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080, q=-1--1, 16 fps, 16384 tbn, 16 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 16000 Hz, mono, fltp, 69 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 aac
frame= 2757 fps=273 q=-1.0 Lsize=   21394kB time=00:02:52.28 bitrate=1017.2kbits/s dup=92 drop=0 speed=17.1x
video:19842kB audio:1492kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.280957%
[libx264 @ 0x7fffda8c2c40] frame I:12    Avg QP:15.18  size:232156
[libx264 @ 0x7fffda8c2c40] frame P:1751  Avg QP:20.38  size:  9540
[libx264 @ 0x7fffda8c2c40] frame B:994   Avg QP:23.59  size:   832
[libx264 @ 0x7fffda8c2c40] consecutive B-frames: 40.7% 29.5% 13.1% 16.8%
[libx264 @ 0x7fffda8c2c40] mb I  I16..4: 44.5% 15.6% 39.9%
[libx264 @ 0x7fffda8c2c40] mb P  I16..4:  0.5%  0.2%  0.2%  P16..4:  9.3%  1.1%  1.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:87.8%
[libx264 @ 0x7fffda8c2c40] mb B  I16..4:  0.1%  0.1%  0.0%  B16..8:  6.2%  0.2%  0.1%  direct: 0.1%  skip:93.1%  L0:31.0% L1:66.2% BI: 2.9%
[libx264 @ 0x7fffda8c2c40] 8x8 transform intra:20.6% inter:17.2%
[libx264 @ 0x7fffda8c2c40] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 40.5% 40.6% 18.4% inter: 3.2% 2.1% 0.3%
[libx264 @ 0x7fffda8c2c40] i16 v,h,dc,p: 40% 33%  8% 19%
[libx264 @ 0x7fffda8c2c40] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 36% 14% 43%  2%  1%  1%  1%  1%  2%
[libx264 @ 0x7fffda8c2c40] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 37% 32% 15%  2%  3%  3%  3%  3%  3%
[libx264 @ 0x7fffda8c2c40] i8c dc,h,v,p: 56% 20% 19%  5%
[libx264 @ 0x7fffda8c2c40] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.7% UV:0.7%
[libx264 @ 0x7fffda8c2c40] ref P L0: 85.4%  5.7%  6.2%  2.7%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fffda8c2c40] ref B L0: 79.1% 18.3%  2.6%
[libx264 @ 0x7fffda8c2c40] ref B L1: 96.6%  3.4%
[libx264 @ 0x7fffda8c2c40] kb/s:943.30
[aac @ 0x7fffda8f1e00] Qavg: 18927.953
```